# Reactstrap: Reset Modal field on close/open in a functional wrapper component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, reactstrap

In parent component that displays list of todo tasks we can either add or edit existing task. For that a separate wrapper was created.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
    Label,
    Input,
    Button,
    Modal,
    ModalHeader,
    ModalBody,
    ModalFooter
} from 'reactstrap';
import DateTimePicker from 'react-datetime-picker';
import { ToDoTask } from '../models/api';

export interface ToDoItemDialoProps {
    visible: boolean,
    item: ToDoTask | undefined,
    onSave: (item: ToDoTask) => void,
    onCancel: () => void
}
const ToDoItemDialog: React.FC<ToDoItemDialoProps> = (props: ToDoItemDialoProps) => {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
    const [description, setDescription] = useState('');
    const [dueDate, setDueDate] = useState<Date>();
    var id = 0;
    /*
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('useEffect called');
    }, [title, description, dueDate ]);
    */
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Modal isOpen={props.visible} autoFocus={false} toggle={props.onCancel}> 
                <ModalHeader>Add your TODO note</ModalHeader>
                <ModalBody>
                    <Label>Title</Label>
                    <Input
                        autoFocus={true}
                        onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)}
                        value={title}
                    />
                    <Label>Optional description</Label>
                    <Input
                        name="text"
                        type="textarea"
                        rows="5"
                        onChange={e => setDescription(e.target.value)}
                        value={description}
                    />
                    <Label>Due by</Label>
                    <DateTimePicker format='dd-MM-yyyy h:mm:ss a'
                        onChange={dateTime => setDueDate(dateTime)}
                        minDate={new Date()}
                        value={dueDate}
                    />
                </ModalBody>
                <ModalFooter>
                    <Button color="primary" onClick={ () => props.onSave({ id: id, title: title, description: description, dueDate: dueDate })}>
                        Save
                    </Button>{' '}
                    <Button color="secondary" onClick={props.onCancel}>
                        Cancel
                    </Button>
                </ModalFooter>
            </Modal>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
export default ToDoItemDialog;
```

Using paradigm that input values should save to state on change and value bound to state I can't figure out how to cleanup all fields once dialog opens again. (Inputs don't seem to need value bound and it solves the problem if we remove *value*, but DateTimePicker won't display value if selected with calendar.)
It opens when parent component sets its *visible* prop.
Basically whenever Ok or Cancel is pressed and then dialog is reopened, input fields are populated from its state.

useEffect seems to run after render and than I don't know how to reset state there.
Component needn't necessarily be functional, so will making it a class help?
Anyway, how to open dialog with empty fields or values passed from props in an *item* property?

Parent component usage is

`<ToDoItemDialog visible={this.state.isModal} item={this.state.currentItem} onSave={this.addToDoItem} onCancel={this.toggle} />`

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, this can be achieved with useEffect hook:

````
        if (props.item) {
            const { id, title, description, dueDate } = props.item;
            setId(id);
            setTitle(title || '');
            setDescription(description || '');
            setDueDate(dueDate ? new Date(dueDate) : null);
        } else {
            setId(0);
            setTitle('');
            setDescription('');
            setDueDate(null);
        }
    }, [props.visible]);```
````